# Are there any native Window animations in Qt 4?

Tags: c++, qt, animation, qt4

I'm thinking like text fade in and slide effects. I imagine implementing this would be rather trivial and plan to do so myself, but wanted to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel first. If it doesn't exist then I'm looking on advice on the best way to implement these.

The 2 things I'm looking to do are fade in text and have the window slide down when resizing, eg if I show a label that was previously hidden it would slide down ~20 pixels instead of just instantly growing 20 pixels larger.

The way I was thinking to implement the first one is, assuming it's possible, get the window/bg color and start it at that and transition it to the font color, if there's alpha channel support that would be even simpler to do (I'm not sure if there is since I haven't messed with colors yet). To do this I'd just choose a transition time period and process it with a for loop or something once the color increments have been determined.

Similarly to do the window transitions I would get the height of the change (not sure how to do that yet), determine the increments of change based on the transition time and in a for loop gradually adjust the size. Sorry if I didn't explain those very clear, I'm trying to get this in before I go to work and figure most of you will know what I'm trying to explain. As always thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

For window resize transition effect, [`QPropertyAnimation`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qpropertyanimation.html) may be the easiest to do since height is a widget property. Fading text might work the same way if the foreground color can be coerced into a property.

Comment: Text color is part of the palette property. So it is a property, but things may get complicated.

Comment: @ypnos: that's what I remember. Some custom widget derived from QLabel with color as a property may be required. That's why I worte "coerced" :)